# Change content in CollectionView by selecting a cell fom table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a table view and a colection view in one view controller.

In table view i have categories for images , and in collection view images.

How can I change to content of collection view when a cell is selected ?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int numberFromArray=[numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *link=[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";


    NSString *imagineURL=[recipeImages objectAtIndex:4];

    rowIndex=indexPath.row+1 ;
    NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowIndex];
    NSString * urlValue = [imagineURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"X"
                                                                withString:strFromInt];




    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlValue]];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    [self.collection reloadData];


}




- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";


    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];


   // NSString *imagineURL=imageTest;

     rowIndex=indexPath.row+1 ;
    NSString *imagineURL=[recipeImages objectAtIndex:1];

    NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowIndex];
    NSString * urlValue = [imagineURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"X"
                                                   withString:strFromInt];




    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlValue]];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];



    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];





    button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(getPicture:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    button.frame = recipeImageView.frame;
    button.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];



    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the changes on`(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Update your array of images and update the UICollectionView

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  self.imagesCollection = //get you images from wherever
  [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: this is work for changin only one image from collection . I update my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal and usual logic.

In your tableView's `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method, put your selected issue while cell is selected.

Choose the one you want `UICollectionViewCell *cell = [myCollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:1]` and do something change like `cell.text = @"Text had changed"`. Don't forget to call `reloadData` at last.

HTH.

Comment: i want to change the all images from collectionView

Comment: @NicoleSD What's `recipeImageView` in your first method? Seems like you don't have any change but just call `[self.collection reloadData]`